# How to get filter conditions dropdown next to textbox when filterrow is enabled in jqxGrid?

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I got a column with filter type textbox and i got filterrow enabled but i need the filter conditions dropdown to also appear next to the textbox because i need to be able to apply multiple conditions like not equal and other filters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is possible, but only by making changes to the `jqxgrid.filter` module, which the licensing seems to allow. I base this answer on the code for jQWidgets v3.4.0. (Of course, it's convenient to de-minify the code first.)

There are switch statements in several functions which switch on the `filtertype` (such as `number` and `textbox`). You can define your own filtertype that shows a textbox with a dropdown list by choosing a new name and adding case statements to fall through to the `number` case in the function definitions `_updatefilterrowui`, `clearfilterrow`, and `refreshfilterrow`. For the function `_addfilterwidget`, you need to add your own case and copy the code for the `number` case, but replace the line saying

```
var A = F._getfiltersbytype("number");
```

with

```
var A = F._getfiltersbytype("string");
```

to populate the dropdown list with the string comparison operators – or you can define your own filtertype, but this of course requires additional adjustments. In the function `_applyfilterfromfilterrow` you also need to add a case based on the code for the `number` case, with some adjustments. Basically, what seems to do the trick is to firstly remove the part about the decimal separator and secondly to not typecast the input string by changing

```
y = k.createfilter(d, new Number(p), w, null, u.cellsformat, C.gridlocalization);
```

to

```
y = k.createfilter(d, p, w, null, u.cellsformat, C.gridlocalization);
```

Note that this answer is possibly not complete, as I haven't done extensive testing (but I am interested to know of any problems, as I am looking for the same functionality as BeyondProgramming).